# Файлы сохраняются не в указанную папку. Автотестирование: Selenium + Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, тестирование

В процессе тестирования мне нужно проверить выгрузку файла с сайта.
Для этого я указываю путь для сохранения файлов.
В options для firefox указаны следующие:

```
path = os.getcwd() + f"/download_{ip}"
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
```

Вообще, я пробовала очень много вариаций, так что дело, скорее всего не в этом, но я уже ни в чем не уверена :(

Проблема в том, что файл не сохраняется по указанному пути, а сохраняется в папке */var/lib/jenkins/Downloads*, хотя для chrome все работает нормально - создается папка, как прописано в коде, и файл сохраняется в нее.
Еще одна странность в том, что при запуске файлов локально все работает как полагается, но при запуске на сервере наблюдается вышеописанная проблема. Код при этом не меняется, да и вообще все аналогично. С правами для сохранения вроде бы все в порядке, потому что в процессе в эту же директорию сохраняются скриншоты.
Возможно, я упускаю что-то элементарное или взгляд замылился. Буду благодарна за любую помощь!

Версии:
Mozilla Firefox 99.0
Selenium 4.1.3

Comment: лучше всё же использовать os.join() вместе с os.getcwd(), чтобы не было недоразумений.

Comment: я пробовала использовать и просто os.getcwd(), и никакого эффекта :(